# How to resolve android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0

Tags: java, android, sqlite, cursor

I've searched for solutions for a long time and still can't find a relevant way to make it work.
I have this method inside an external **myDBClass.java** in Android studio to find last inserted row.

```
public Cursor lastrow() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try{
         SQLiteDatabase db;
         db = this.getReadableDatabase(); // Read Data
         String query = "SELECT ID As _id, Spinpos, Details, Setfor from alarm order by ID DESC limit 1";
         Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
         if(cursor != null)
            {
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                return cursor;
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }

         } catch (Exception e) {
           return null;
         }
      }
```

Then I execute it in **MainActivity.java**

```
 myDBClass myDb = new myDBClass(this);      
 Cursor cursor  = myDb.lastrow();  
 String SongID = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Spinpos"));  
 Toast.makeText(this,SongID,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

It throws android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException. Please provide me a solution.

Comment: how about showing the lastcur method so we can answer?  You have shown your lastrow method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Cursor** is initialized to position -1, so when you call **moveToNext**() will return true if the cursor reach position 0, that mean the db fetched at least one value.

Use this

```
 if(cursor.moveToNext()){

     //database fetched at least one value
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You also need to check that your cursor has result, something like this:

`if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0)`

Comment: Hi @Panczur, I think query doesn't return null. It either returns a cursor or throws an exception. By calling if(moveToFirst()){} or if(moveToNext()){}, it returns true if cursor is not empty. 
[link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)